# UV unwrap from location or plane from diffuse?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, workflow, unity

[image]

I have a hair mesh that is done by somebody who I think was probably very professional (a worker for the Unity game engine).

I am trying to figure out how exactly he did that hair mesh.

Sometimes it looks as if he just inserted a plane and then put an alpha masked image on it based on location, and other times I think he took a look at one image and thought about where he could use different parts of that image.

I don't really understand the work-flow yet. Can anybody tell me how he did this?

I have uploaded the file [here](http://www.onscreensoftware.de/hair.zip).
Unfortunately I don't know how to put the diffuse texture into the .blend file permanently, so I have included it in the zip file.

Comment: without a blend file or more information, i think this question is off topic as we can't study it to see exactly what happened. To avoid closure, edit your question to add a link to a .blend. use a service like [GiantCowFilms.com](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: i edited to make it a little easier to understand

Comment: Well, to start with, he used an animation in the process, and there's a UV channel active. Otherwise it's above my paygrade.